# Return the special character in string

Tags: excel, vba

I'm able to find and replace the special characters in a string but I'm trying to return that special character. Here's what i got so far.

```
Function replaceSpecialCharacter(theString As String)

Dim StrTest As String
Dim Result  As String
Dim Reg1    As Object
Dim matches
StrTest = theString

Set Reg1 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With Reg1
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "[-[\]{}()%*+?\\/^$|#\s]" ' escape special characters pattern
End With

If Reg1.test(StrTest) Then
    Result = Reg1.Replace(StrTest, Result)
End If
replaceSpecialCharacter = Result
End Function
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "ALL units such as percentage"?  Do you mean all characters which are not a-z or 0-9, or something else?  How do you want to "return" them?

Comment: so you want to pass in a string, and then the result be the special character(s) that were identified/replaced in the string?

Comment: What do you mean by "return as a string"? To return "%" if it exists in the string? To replace it firstly? What if it exists in many places? And why do you need it returned?

Comment: I want to know what the special character is in the string. and i want it to return as a string so i can use it else where.

Comment: @FaneDuru it will only exist one time.

Comment: Are you asking how to *capture* the match?

Comment: Then you can simple use: `Dim return as String`, then `If inStr("the string", "%") > 0 Then return = "%"`

Comment: @JohnColeman YES. I want to know what special character matches.

Comment: @FaneDuru it may be another character. I don't want to be just percentage. could be any.

Comment: @TomBrunberg reread post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is only 1 match and you want to return it, you can use a `matches` object, returned by the `Execute` method of the regulat expression object:

```
Function findSpecialCharacter(theString As String)

    Dim StrTest As String
    Dim Result  As String
    Dim Reg1    As Object
    Dim matches As Object
    StrTest = theString
    
    Set Reg1 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With Reg1
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "[-[\]{}()%*+?\\/^$|#\s]" ' escape special characters pattern
    End With
    Set matches = Reg1.Execute(theString)
    findSpecialCharacter = matches(0).Value 'assumes just 1 match, at index 0
        
End Function
```